# debsecan Fix CVE on debian

Tags: linux, debian, security, patch, vulnerabilities

I just installed `debsecan` on Debian 8.1 to view the vulnerabilities that I have, and there were quite a few. Searching the web I see that most of them have a fix but I don't manage to figure out how to apply a patch for them. Here is a mere example of a couple of "remotely exploitable, high urgency".

- CVE-2015-5621 `libsnmp30` (fixed, remotely exploitable, high urgency)
- CVE-2016-2052 `libharfbuzz-icu0` (fixed, remotely exploitable, high urgency)
- CVE-2015-5364 `linux-libc-dev` (fixed, remotely exploitable, high urgency)
- CVE-2015-5364 `linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64` (fixed, remotely exploitable, high urgency, obsolete)
- CVE-2015-5600 `openssh-server` (fixed, remotely exploitable, high urgency)

How can I patch these packages and the ones that I still have on the system that have a "fix"? I know all of them must be fixed differently but a pointer to where and how to start would be awesome!

Just in case it helps, this is my `sources.list` file:

```
###### Debian Main Repos
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib 
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib 

###### Debian Update Repos
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib 
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-proposed-updates main contrib 
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib 
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-proposed-updates main contrib 

###### Other Debian
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

Comment: I'll assume you are on the Stable branch. is it Jessie or Wheezy? Have you confirmed you have the repos for http://security.debian.org/ in your sources.list? have you enabled backport repos? http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/

Comment: I am running Jessie stable branch, and I have "deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main" with the src on my sources list. I added and enabled the backports and it removed a couple but still there are a LOT left.